# Session doesn't get cleared

Tags: php, session, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I have a google chrome extension talking to a PHP script via XHR. I have a flag in the PHP script to check if a button is clicked in a popup if proper POST data is sent. If this button is clicked, the current session needs to be destroyed and when new data is entered by clicking the add button it shouldn't be appending data to an existing session but start a new one instead. It's currently just re-appending the data to the array. It's as if the clear session command is being ignored, however the IF statement is being called correctly to the console. How do I get the clear session statement to clear the session?

PHP script:

```
<?php $json = $_POST['data'];

if($json['button'] == "clear"){
session_unset();
session_destroy();
echo 'session destroyed!'; //being called to console
exit();
}

if (!isset ($_COOKIE[ini_get($_SESSION['data'])])) {
    session_start();
  }

if(!isset($_SESSION['data'])){
    $_SESSION['data'] = $json;
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['data'])){
    array_push($_SESSION['data'], $json);
    }

print_r($_SESSION['data']);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `session_start()` first:

```
if($json['button'] == "clear")
{
  session_start(); // <-- first
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  echo 'session destroyed!'; //being called to console
  exit();
}
```